# Converting a generator into a list, but getting Error: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'decode' (python 3.6.4)

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error, generator, tokenize

I am working with a text in **utf-8**.
I want to tokenize it and then convert it into a list.
However I get the following error.

```
import nltk, jieba, re, os

with open('file.txt') as f:
    tokenized_text = jieba.cut(f,cut_all=True)

type(tokenized_text)
generator

word_list = list(tokenized_text)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-16b25477c71d> in <module>()
----> 1 list(new)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jieba/__init__.py in cut(self, sentence, cut_all, HMM)
280             - HMM: Whether to use the Hidden Markov Model.
281         '''
--> 282         sentence = strdecode(sentence)
283 
284         if cut_all:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jieba/_compat.py in strdecode(sentence)
 35     if not isinstance(sentence, text_type):
 36         try:
---> 37             sentence = sentence.decode('utf-8')
 38         except UnicodeDecodeError:
 39             sentence = sentence.decode('gbk', 'ignore')

AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I understand the problem lies somewhere in the jieba package.
I also tried to change the code into

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
new = jieba.cut(f,cut_all=False)
```

but got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jieba.cut` takes a string, not a file. This is explained in the [readme](https://github.com/fxsjy/jieba#main-functions).

Comment: I see. It would have been sufficient to write the code as follow: `with open('file.txt').read() as f:
new = jieba.cut(f,cut_all=False)`

Comment: It's a little stupid that they can't accept either. All of pandas' IO functions can do so, and it isn't that hard to implement.